# How to calculate the percentage of a value contemplating negative numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

```
min = 0
max = 100
v = 50
```

Given those values, I can calculate the percentage of "completion" for `v` within the range `[min,max]` like this:

```
(100.0 / max) * v
```

And I get `50%` - the desired value.

As you can see, I don't even use the `min` variable. So I have problems when this happens:

```
min = -100
max = 100
v = -50
```

I would expect the above values to produce `25%`. But clearly, my earlier formula can't do that.

What can I do to calculate such values then? What changes are necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of the interval $[min,max]$ is $$max-min=100-(-100)=100+100=200$$

The length of the interval $[min,v]$ is $$v-min=(-50)-(-100)=-50+100=50$$

So the completion for $v$ is $$\frac{50}{200}=25\%$$

Note that in your first case $min$ was $0$ so $\frac{v-min}{max-min}\cdot100$
equaled $\frac{v}{max}\cdot100=\frac{100}{max}\cdot v$ so your formula
worked in this case because $min$ equaled $0$ and did not work in
the second case because $min$ did not equal $0$ .